# Why isn't this scrollLeft JS function working on my local wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

It works fine in codepen, I'm not getting any errors in console, and other JS is working on the same page.  I'm adding it using the header footer code manager plug in.

The `mouseover` function is working, and in [codepen](https://codepen.io/jack-mullinkosson/pen/OJgpZMy), with this `scrollLeft` function, I'm able to scroll through my gallery by clicking the button. But in my locally hosted wordpress site, clicking the button does nothing. I included the `jQuery.noConflict` bit after reading similar questions and seeing that that worked for other people, but it hasn't worked for me. Here's the code:

```js
const videos = document.querySelectorAll(".polystar");

for (const video of videos) {
  video.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    video.play()
  }, false);
  video.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    video.pause()
  }, false);
}
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("slide");
    button.onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("container").scrollLeft += 310;
    };
    var back = document.getElementById("slideBack");
    back.onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("container").scrollLeft -= 310;
    };
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
  div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: black;
}

video {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.first:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.second:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.third:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.fourth:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.fifth:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.sixth:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%);
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1px #000;
  font-family: arial;
}

.first:hover .overlay-text {
  display: none;
}

.second:hover .overlay-text {
  display: none;
}

.third:hover .overlay-text {
  display: none;
}

.fourth:hover .overlay-text {
  display: none;
}

.fifth:hover .overlay-text {
  display: none;
}

.sixth:hover .overlay-text {
  display: none;
}

#slideBack {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 30%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
}

#slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 60%;
  right: 0;
  top: 30%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
}

.first:hover,
.second:hover,
.third:hover,
.fourth:hover,
.fifth:hover,
.sixth:hover {
  animation: fadeIn .4s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .4s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn .4s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn .4s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn .4s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .overlayzinho {
    background-color: black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 190px;
    z-index: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="first">
    <video muted="" loop="" class="polystar">
        <source src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ChWorker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/MosEgo.jpg">
    <div class="overlay-text">"Group"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <video muted="" loop="" class="polystar">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/432406907.hd.mp4?s=f35b5f202d573efa75d9293d213fc3be0927fd85&amp;profile_id=172&amp;oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/best-e1631205169449.png">
    <div class="overlay-text">"That's a Lie"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <video muted="" loop="" class="polystar">
        <source src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ChWorker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/birds-thumbnail.png">
    <div class="overlay-text">"Birds"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth">
    <video muted="" loop="" class="polystar">
        <source src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ChWorker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Escalator.png">
    <div class="overlay-text">"Chinese Worker"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fifth">
    <video muted="" loop="" class="polystar">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/432406907.hd.mp4?s=f35b5f202d573efa75d9293d213fc3be0927fd85&amp;profile_id=172&amp;oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/STILL-10-e1631205191960.png">
    <div class="overlay-text">"Divided"</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sixth">
    <video muted="" loop="" class="polystar">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/432406907.hd.mp4?s=f35b5f202d573efa75d9293d213fc3be0927fd85&amp;profile_id=172&amp;oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="http://jackmullinkosson.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ForTheSetEdit5-e1631205229115.png">
    <div class="overlay-text">"For the Set"</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="slideBack" type="button">Prev</button>
<button id="slide" type="button">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this question, the problem was that I didn't change the container id when I put it on my website, so the javascript that wasn't working was probably referring to a preexisting container already built into my wordpress theme. When I changed the id of the container to something unique, the scroll button began to work.